# Stuck bathtub faucet stem

Tags: plumbing

[image]tried spraying PB blaster, WD40, warming it, and it just will not turn. Think I may cut around the whole thing so I can get a monkey wrench on it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have been wrenching on the wrong piece (the stem). You need to unscrew the entire assembly at the **valve body**. The body is deeper in the wall, if you shine a flashlight in there you will see where you need to unscrew it. It takes a special deep socket made just for that purpose:

[image]

[image]

The picture shows the person using a rod to turn the socket; you may need to put a pipe wrench on the socket to get it to break free. Ensure the water is shut off before you do this.

Pictures shamelessly grabbed off of the internet.